# expected primary-expression before 'led'

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse with google test. I wrote the code below but it shows the error "expected primary-expression before 'led'".

The code is as following:

LedDriverTest.cpp

```
#include "C:\googletest-master\googletest\include\gtest\gtest.h"
#include "LedDriver.h"
TEST(LedDriverTest, LedInitial){
    LedDriver led;
    EXPECT_EQ(0x00, led.getLedStatus());
}
```

LedDriver.h

```
#ifndef LEDDRIVER_H_
#define LEDDRIVER_H_

namespace LedDriver {

class LedDriver {
public:
    LedDriver();
    virtual ~LedDriver();
    unsigned char getLedStatus();
private:
    unsigned char status;
};
} /* namespace LedDriver */
#endif /* LEDDRIVER_H_ */
```

LedDriver.cpp

```
#include "LedDriver.h"
namespace LedDriver {

LedDriver::LedDriver() {
    status = 0x00;
}

LedDriver::~LedDriver() {
}

unsigned char LedDriver::getLedStatus(){
    return status;
}
} /* namespace LedDriver */
```

"LedDriver.h" and "LedDriver.cpp" are in the same project named "LedDriver". "LedDriverTest.cpp" is in the other project named "LedDriverTest". The GCC Compiler's include path of "LedDriverTest" project is set to "LedDriver" project.

Please tell me what's wrong and how I can solve it.

Comment: Is your `TEST` function in the `LedDriver` namespace? If not, you'll need to fully-qualify any types inside it, like this: `LedDriver::LedDriver led` (or: `using namespace LedDriver`, or: `using LedDriver::LedDriver`).

Comment: Try `LedDriver::LedDriver led;`.

Comment: When I added 'using namespace LedDriver' , the error 'reference to "LedDriver" is ambiguous' appeared. I tried to add 'LedDriver::' but 'undefined reference to `LedDriver::LedDriver::LedDriver()' appeared.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `using namepace LedDriver` at the top of the LedDriverTest.cpp file.

The compilation error is caused by the fact your class `LedDriver` is declared in the namespace `LedDriver`, but you do not specify this and the compiler only looks for it in the default namespace during compilation of LedDriverTest.cpp. The `using` clause tells it to look in the namespace `LedDriver` as well as the default namespace when resolving names.

You could explicitly use the `LedDriver::` prefix to specifically tell the compiler which namespace to look in if you prefer. However, given your usage - the testing of LedDriver - it is natural and easily readable if you you the `using` directive. The reason is the test file is closely associated with the tested functionality - so you're not making the code any less clear by omitting that namespace with every declaration. Also, it helps you remove the clutter of `LedDriver::` used repeatedly and often within the file.

Comment: This would indeed fix the compilation error, but you haven't explained why and you haven't mentioned the alternatives (importing just the `LedDriver` class or just using fully qualified names).